# How can i fix the codes below?

Tags: android, logout, nullable

I copied the below code from another site as I thought would have saved me some time. But I got 3 issues.

1. @Override says Method does not ovveride method from its superclass
2. getActivity on Toast.makeText (Cannot resolve method)
3. getActivity on Intent (Cannot resolve method)

they are in red. I hope you can help.

```
package com.mz4466.photowar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";

    //firebase
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    //widgets
    private Button mSignOut;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
        mSignOut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logout_button);

        setupFirebaseListener();

        mSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to sign out the user.");
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    private void setupFirebaseListener(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseListener: setting up the auth state listener.");
        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user != null){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: signed_in: " + user.getUid());
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: signed_out");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mAuthStateListener != null){
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've copied is fragment code not an activity, so you need to make some changes

First change any `getActivity()` to `HomeActivity.this`

Secondly you need to override the `onCreate()` not the `onCreateView()` method so change these lines

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
```

to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

and finally remove the `view.` from this line `mSignOut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logout_button);` and completely remove this line `return view;`

Comment: Thank you so much. You made it work and now I understand that I need to find out more about Fragments.